# Ripple Effect (inkwell) in Containers, positioned with margins in a Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using the following code in Flutter, hoping to get a ripple effect (InkWell()) in the green and red areas.  Yes they are supposed to be buttons, used in car by a copilot while driving on dirt roads.
I can get the ripple effect behind the colored areas by using the Material Class, but not in front of it and it will not respect the bounderies set by the margins of the containers.

*Not using types right now, still in early dev stages, any tips on better or shorter code are very welcome*

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

````
      context: context,
      // barrierColor: Color(0x55888899),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 300,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xcc232930),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
              topRight: Radius.circular(40),
            ),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              //Background
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        offset: new Offset(0.0, 3.0),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                      )
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
                  height: 245),
              Container(
                //horizontal line
                height: 1,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 15,
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 122, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
              ),
              Container(
                //vertical line
                height: 245,
                width: 1,
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
              ),

              // Big F
              Container(
                width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 15,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  "F",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 180,
                    shadows: [
                      Shadow(
                          blurRadius: 15,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          offset: Offset(0, 0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

             
              // Accept button
              Container(
                width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 16,
                height: 122,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 1,
                  //top: 100,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40)),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Accepted, adding to ControlCard");
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                  enableFeedback: true,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                    child: Text("Accept",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shadows: [
                            Shadow(
                                blurRadius: 15,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                offset: Offset(0, 0))
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // Decline button
              Container(
                width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 16,
                height: 122,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 1,
                  top: 123,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(40)),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Declined");
                  },
                  enableFeedback: true,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
                    child: Text("Decline",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shadows: [
                            Shadow(
                                blurRadius: 15,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                offset: Offset(0, 0))
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Positioned widget to position the Containers within the Stack. ClipRRect is required to stop the splash from going out of boundaries.

Please see working code below or check it out on [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/d1b2350a64826357a5d417b0f1703334) https://dartpad.dev/d1b2350a64826357a5d417b0f1703334 :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Colors.white;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xcc232930),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
          topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          //Background
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 3.0),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                  )
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
              height: 245),
          Container(
            //horizontal line
            height: 1,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 15,
            color: Colors.white,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 122, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
          ),
          Container(
            //vertical line
            height: 245,
            width: 1,
            color: Colors.white,
            margin:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
          ),

          // Big F
          Container(
            width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 15,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
            child: Text(
              "F",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 180,
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                      blurRadius: 15, color: Colors.black, offset: Offset(0, 0))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // Accept button
          Positioned(
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 1,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(40)),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Accepted, adding to ControlCard");
                  },
                  splashColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                  enableFeedback: true,
                  child: Container(
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 16,
                    height: 122,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Accept",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 32,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shadows: [
                            Shadow(
                                blurRadius: 15,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                offset: Offset(0, 0))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // Decline button
          Positioned(
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 + 1,
            top: 123,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(40)),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Declined");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 16,
                    height: 122,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Decline",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 32,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                  blurRadius: 15,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 0))
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```